# How to grant only local login access to user in Oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Hi i have readed some tutorials and official Oracle docs.
I'm trying to create an user who only can access locally to the instance.

For example in MySQL is so simple:

> If you want to create a user only in localhost:
>
> CREATE USER Bob@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

But in Oracle I don't know how to do this and it appears to be very complex.

Any comments or docs will be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to have a user that can only log in from the local database?  The only time that would seem to make sense is if you're creating an account for a DBA.  There are specific settings that allow or disallow remote connections as SYSDBA which may be what you're after.  It's also possible that you just want a garden-variety operating system authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, a user is identified by the combination of `user` and `host`. Even with a common `user` value, with different `host` values, those rows in mysql.user are separate entries, each has its own separate password and own  separate set of privileges.

Oracle doesn't do that.

The only way to prevent a user from logging on except from some specified terminals or hosts would be to use an `AFTER LOGON` trigger to perform some checks and raise an exception.

As a rough example (N.B. this is not tested. And this will need to be modified, depending on how you want to identify a user as logging in from an "allowed" host, protocol, ip address, etc.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER afterlogon
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   IF USERNAME='BOB' THEN
      IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') = '127.0.0.1' THEN
         -- logon allowed
         NULL;
      ELSIF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') = 'myserver'
         -- logon allowed
         NULL;
      ELSE
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Logon not allowed');
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Be very careful with `AFTER LOGON` trigger, that gets fired for every logon. Only accounts with sufficient privileges can bypass the trigger.

You'd need to tinker with the conditions you want to check to determine that a logon should be allowed or not. There are several different values available from `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', )`.

---

Another option is to create the user as `OPS$BOB`, a local operating system authenticated user. (The prefix for the username is determined by the `OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX` parameter, the default for that (I believe) is still `'OPS$'`... but that's significantly different from MySQL.

Comment: If you grant `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` to your user, then this trigger will be bypassed. `DBA` role has this privilege by default.

Comment: @Wernfried: Thank for the clarification. I know that `SYSDBA` user and users with `DBA` role can bypass the logon trigger, or at least, bypass any exceptions thrown by the trigger. I wasn't sure about what the actual privilege was; thanks for clarifying that. (I left it ambiguous in my answer, "sufficient privileges".) In this case, since OP wants to "lockdown" user `BOB`, to prevent logon except from allowed host/server/ip, it shouldn't be a problem to *not* grant that system privilege. (No DBA worth his salt would have that privilege granted to users that didn't require it.)